# How do I free a linked list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, free, nodes, dynamic-memory-allocation

In the C language, I have something like:

```
typedef struct bucket {
int value;
struct bucket *next;
} Bucket;

typedef struct table {
int size;
Bucket **buckets;
} Table;
```

Now I do `Table *t = malloc(sizeof(Table));`

And `t->buckets = calloc(10, sizeof(Bucket));`

Freeing table *t is `free(t)`; correct?

And now, how would I be able to free the buckets linked list and every single node?

Comment: does it compile? shouldn't `struct next *bucket` be struct `bucket *bucket`;

Comment: sorry that should be struct bucket *next

Answer (score 1):

You should have a corresponding call to `free` for every `malloc`/`calloc`, in a symmetric manner:

```
Table *t = malloc(sizeof(Table));
t->buckets = calloc(10, sizeof(Bucket));
...
free(t->buckets);
free(t);
```

If you miss freeing `t->buckets`, you'll be leaking memory because the `Table` struct only contains a pointer to the buckets and doesn't contain them. The compiler is not going to insert it there for you, either.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that could go wrong is freeing a node and then trying to access the next node, so you need to save the next pointer first.

```
Bucket *bptr, *next;

bptr = *t;
while (bptr) {
    next = bptr->next;
    free(bptr);
    bptr = next;
} 
free(t);
t=NULL;
```